# Running out of memory because of large input data (individual file) size, stuck at epoch 1

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, large-data

I am training a Conv1D autoencoder but when I try to apply model.fit() it gets stuck at epoch1/2 regardless of how small the batch size is. When running on Colab, with random data of the same size, it runs out of memory and disconnects (not sure if GPU RAM or normal RAM)
The code runs for smaller data and I also tried it on my personal workstation with RTX 3090 and 128GB of memory.
I am not sure what I can do to fix the issue, the data size is only 4MB, while GPU memory is 24GB and PC memory is 128GB but even with a dataset of 2 and batch size of 2 it still gets stuck.
code and colab link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KL3tYnJc8rNn-5eqIPtdQrheogfwic0h?usp=sharing
`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense,Conv1D,MaxPooling1D,UpSampling1D,Flatten,add,Cropping1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D,Cropping2D,Reshape


def cnn1D(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',activation0='relu',activation='linear',x_shape=(531441,1),pooling1=3,pooling2=3,filter1=64,filter2=64,kernel=3):
    
    in_dim = x_shape
    input_img = Input(shape=in_dim) #input layer
    #conv1
    x1 = Conv1D(filter1, kernel, activation=activation0, padding='same')(input_img) # 100 100 64 
    x2 = MaxPooling1D(pooling1, padding='same')(x1) # 50 50 64
    #conv2
    x2 = Conv1D(filter2, kernel, activation=activation0, padding='same')(x2) # 50 50 128
    x3 = MaxPooling1D(pooling2, padding='same')(x2) # 25 25 128
    

    #de-conv2
    encoded = Conv1D(filter2, kernel, activation=activation0, padding='same')(x3) # 25 25 128
    y=UpSampling1D(pooling2)(encoded) # 50 50 128
    

    #de-conv1
    y=Conv1D(filter1, kernel, activation=activation0, padding='same')(y) # 50 50 128
    y=UpSampling1D(pooling1)(y) # 100 100 128


    decoded = Conv1D(x_shape[-1], 11, activation=activation, padding='same')(y) # 100 100 4

    cnn = Model(input_img, decoded)

    cnn.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer)#,metrics=['accuracy']) #adadelta
    cnn.summary()
    return cnn
nn2 = cnn1D()

import numpy as np

training_dataset = np.random.normal(size=(10,531441, 1))

nn2.fit(training_dataset, training_dataset, epochs=2, batch_size=2,validation_data=(training_dataset,training_dataset))
```

`
Note: I come from physics background so sorry if the answer is obvious and I did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

The session crashes, runs out of memory and disconnects Because `cpu mode` is unable to provide high Ram runtime to run the above code as this code dataset has high dimensions`(200, 531441, 1, 1)`. You need to run this code by selecting `gpu mode` in `Google colab`.

> Select Runtime - Change runtime type - Hardware accelerator - GPU
> (from dropdown) - Save

I replicated the same code in `Google colab` with `Tensorflow=2.8` by selecting `gpu mode` and it ran successfully.

```
nn2.fit(training_dataset, training_dataset, epochs=2, batch_size=2,validation_data=(training_dataset,training_dataset))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
100/100 [==============================] - 83s 663ms/step - loss: 0.9914 - val_loss: 0.9889
Epoch 2/2
100/100 [==============================] - 68s 686ms/step - loss: 0.9869 - val_loss: 0.9857
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fd2f0968c10>
```

I also tried by changing the `epochs = 10` and `batch_size=16`

```
nn2.fit(training_dataset, training_dataset, epochs=10, batch_size=16,validation_data=(training_dataset,training_dataset))
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
13/13 [==============================] - 113s 6s/step - loss: 0.9855 - val_loss: 0.9855
Epoch 2/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9852 - val_loss: 0.9852
Epoch 3/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9848 - val_loss: 0.9849
Epoch 4/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9850 - val_loss: 0.9846
Epoch 5/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9841 - val_loss: 0.9839
Epoch 6/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9839 - val_loss: 0.9834
Epoch 7/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9835 - val_loss: 0.9833
Epoch 8/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9832 - val_loss: 0.9830
Epoch 9/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9829 - val_loss: 0.9827
Epoch 10/10
13/13 [==============================] - 62s 5s/step - loss: 0.9826 - val_loss: 0.9826
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fd28663d290>
```